# Use set as argument to Redis command

Tags: redis, key-value-store, nosql

I'm pretty new to Redis, so I'm not entirely sure what's possible. However, I was wondering, if I have a set of key names:

```
SADD set-1 key-1 key-2
```

Can I use those as an argument to another command, like DEL, without having to do a round trip?

Something like:

```
DEL (SMEMBERS set-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without scripting. You'll have to make the round trip.

```
eval "redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('smembers', ARGV[1])))" 0 set-1
```

or if you expect a lot of keys in your set:

```
eval "for _,k in ipairs(redis.call('smembers', ARGV[1])) do redis.call('del', k) end" 0 set-1
```

Comment: How do you do it with scripting?